# datepicker in a html page with for loop is not working on second instance onwards

Tags: jquery, html, for-loop, datepicker

I am using datepicker in a html page, it is working fine in the first instance in a for loop, but on second instance of for loop condition, datepicker is not working

The version of the jquery is

```
<link href="jQueryAssets/jquery.ui.datepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="jQueryAssets/jquery.ui-1.10.4.datepicker.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And the part of the code in my html form is as below. 
I want to run the form in for loop with datepicker. 
But date picker is coming on the first instance only....??
Please help

```
<table align="center">
<?php
$wno = $_POST['no'];
$wname = $_POST['name'];    
?>
    <form method='post' action=''>
        <tr>    
            <td colspan='2' align="center"><input type='text' name='no' class='tfield' value="<?php echo$wno?>" readonly /></td>
            <td colspan='2' align="center"><input type='text' name='name' class='tfield' value="<?php echo$wname?>" readonly /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th class='tabdata'>Log</th>
            <th class='tabdata'>Top Depth</th>
            <th class='tabdata'>Bottom Depth</th>
            <th class='tabdata'>Date of Log</th>
        </tr>   
<?php 
        $number=$_POST['nologs'];
        for($i=1;$i<=$number;$i++){
?>  

        <tr>
            <th colspan="4" align="center" class='tabdata'>File No: <?php echo$i?></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input name='logs[]' type='text' required="required" placeholder="Logs" autocomplete="off" class='tabdata'>
            </td>

            <td>
                <input type='float' required="required" name='bottom[]' placeholder="Bottom Depth" class='tabdata'>
            </td>

            <td>
                <input type='float' required="required" name='top[]' placeholder="Top Depth" class='tabdata'>
            </td>

            <td>
                <input type='text' required="required" id="datej" name='date[]' placeholder="Date of Logging" class='tabdata'>  
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
<?php } ?>
        <tr>
            <td colspan='4' align='center'><input type='submit' value='Save' name='submit' class='button'/></td>
        </tr>
    </form>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$( "#datej" ).datepicker({
}); 
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of instantiating it on an `id` (e.g. `$('#datej')`), you need to do it by `class` (e.g. `$('.datej')`). Valid HTML only uses an `id` one time, so if you have multiple objects with the same `id` it is not valid HTML. The way the selector works it will only select the first instance of an `id`.

Comment: Thanks, now it is working when i used class instead of id